# Case When Condition in Where Clause. Use filter condition if it matches the case when condition only

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use case when condition in where clause to filter select statement.
For Eg:

```
Select * from table_name 
where source ='UHC'
and 
to_char(termdate,'YYYYMM') <= '201603';
```

But i want second filter condition to work only if policy number is '1'. For Eg:

```
case when policy_number = '1' then to_char(termdate,'YYYYMM') <= '201603';
```

if the policy number is not 1 then only 1st where clause should work but if policy number is 1 then both the where clause should work.
i hope i made my situation clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need case at all:

```
Select * from table_name 
where source ='UHC'
and ((policy_number = '1' and to_char(termdate,'YYYYMM') <= '201603') 
     or nvl(policy_number, '0') != '1');
```

With case condition will be like:

```
where source ='UHC' and case when policy_number = '1' then to_char(termdate,'YYYYMM') else '000000' end <= '201603');
```

in else you need something that is always less than `'201603'`. Another problem here is why you're comparing numbers as varchars? Is it really what you need?